# Incorrect datetime value: '12-Mar-19' for function str_to_date

Tags: mysql

I have column which has the data type as `date`. I need to insert date values which are in string format and they follow this structure `12-Mar-19`. I tried to use this mysql function `STR_TO_DATE('12-Mar-19', '%c/%e/%Y %r')` but it gives me an error: `Incorrect datetime value: '12-Mar-19' for function str_to_date`.
How can I overcome this.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: It doesn't account for the error message, but wouldn't you want '%d-%b-%y' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a format string that matches your date literal:

```
STR_TO_DATE('12-Mar-19', '%d-%M-%y')
```